# Adding element in Java Netbeans generated combo box

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I'm having some problem in adding new elements to the combo box. The code is created by Netbeans Form Editor, because of this I only have access to modify the event listeners. The elements cant be predefined because the elements are in a database and constantly expanding. Currently the combo box has only one element and i would like it to update according to the values from the database. Thank you for your time folks.

```
package Interface;

/**
 *
* @author Raam
 */
public class Welcome extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Welcome
 */
public Welcome() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("addNewRecord");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Add New Record", "Class", "Section", "Student" }));
    jComboBox1.setToolTipText("Add New Record");
    jComboBox1.setName("AddNewRecord"); // NOI18N
    jComboBox1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1FocusGained(evt);
        }
    });

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Choose Class" }));
    jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Open Database");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(51, 51, 51)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 116, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jComboBox1FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       

    jComboBox1.addElement(); //Tried this, not working
}                                      

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Welcome().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the ítem in the model:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) jComboBox1.getModel();
model.addElement("new ítem");
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by going to properties of the combo box then to >> model. As the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39689417/5737654